# Why is MFMailComposeViewController returning MFMailComposeResultFailed?

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, email-attachments

I'm facing a strange issue in my app and I need your help !
I am using a MFMailComposeViewController to send emails with attachment data. The attachment is either a PDF, a CSV or a XLS file. A ZIP file can also be added to the mail.

Everything works fine in most cases but sometimes (actually quite often), when the attachment is a XLS and a ZIP is added, I receive multiple memory warnings and the composer returns MFMailComposeResultFailed, with an error that doesn't help at all (only saying code error 1, "The operation couldn’t be completed. (MFMailComposeErrorDomain error 1.)").

My question is why does it do that ? I assume the memory warnings are telling me something is not well managed but I can't figure out what...

Here is my code for sending the email

```
-(void) sendMail {

    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; 
    [self prepareMailPicker:picker];

    NSString *filePath = [self getFilePath:pType];

    NSString *zipFile = [self getZipPath];

    NSString *mimeType;
    int userPhoto = [User getCSVPhoto];

    switch (pType) {
        case EPDF:
            mimeType = @"application/pdf";
            userPhoto = [User getPDFPhoto];
            break;
        case ECSV:
            mimeType = @"text/csv";
            break;
        case EExcel:
            mimeType = @"application/vnd.ms-excel";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    NSData *attachmentData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [picker addAttachmentData:attachmentData mimeType:mimeType fileName:[filePath lastPathComponent]];

    if (userPhoto == 1 && shouldAddZip) {
        NSData *zipData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:zipFile];
        [picker addAttachmentData:zipData mimeType:@"application/zip" fileName:[zipFile lastPathComponent]];
    }

    shouldAddZip = NO;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

-(void) prepareMailPicker:(MFMailComposeViewController*)picker {

    picker.mailComposeDelegate = (id<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>)self;

    picker.navigationBar.tintColor = grayDark;

    [picker setSubject:[TextManager textForKey:@"EMAIL_SUBJECT"]];

    NSString *email = [[User currentUser] getEmail];

    if (email && ![email isEqualToString:@""])
        [picker setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:email]];

    NSString *emailBody = [TextManager textForKey:@"EMAIL_TEXT"];
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
}
```

Any help would be grately apreciated !

EDIT: as asked by @matt, here is a log to prove that nothing is set to nil :

```
filePath : /var/mobile/Applications/A57F5CD2-E3FE-4417-8810-D746A22CF434/Documents/iNdF_Export_2012-11-19.xls
zipFile : /var/mobile/Applications/A57F5CD2-E3FE-4417-8810-D746A22CF434/Documents/iNdF_recus_2012-11-19.zip
attachmentData : (NSConcreteData *) <0x1d9c3c20> 53 874 bytes
zipData : (NSConcreteData *) <0x1f989100> 6 838 456 bytes
```

Comment: At what point in your code are you getting the error?

Comment: I get the error in the delegate method `-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error`

Comment: Are you sure nothing is nil? You're using a lot of personal methods for which you are not showing us the code. How do we know what getZipPath does? How do we know that zipData isn't coming out nil because the path in getZipPath is wrong? Add logging to prove that everything is what you think it should be.

Comment: Error 1 is "`MFMailComposeErrorCodeSendFailed` An error occurred while trying to queue or send the email message." I guess that doesn't provide much more information.

Comment: Yes I unserstand that. What I don't understand is why ? I can repeat this bug over and over and some rare times, my code actually works and the email is sent.

Comment: Hello, I am having the same problem. You found a solution for this memory error?

Answer (score 1):

as you say, the problem seems most probably to do with memory management, given the memory warnings you are receiving.

your code is retaining a reference count to the attachmentData from the first file even as it goes out to get the zipData for the second file.  internally, the picker is probably copying that data …

so the more you can do to release your references to large data as early as possible, the more likely you are not to get the memory warnings.

and if the problem is that the picker is unable to finish the attachment due to running out of memory, and you are able to get through it by doing early release, then breaking up the code in the following way may help you.

```
- (void)sendMailPicker:(MFMailComposeViewController*)picker addAttachmentUsingMimeType:(NSString*)mimeType {
    NSString *filePath = [self getFilePath:pType];
    NSData *attachmentData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [picker addAttachmentData:attachmentData mimeType:mimeType fileName:[filePath lastPathComponent]];
}

- (void)sendMailAddPhotoUsingPicker:(MFMailComposeViewController*)picker {
    NSString *zipFile = [self getZipPath];
    NSData *zipData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:zipFile];
    [picker addAttachmentData:zipData mimeType:@"application/zip" fileName:[zipFile lastPathComponent]];
}

- (void)sendMail {

    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; 
    [self prepareMailPicker:picker];

    NSString *mimeType;
    int userPhoto = [User getCSVPhoto];

    switch (pType) {
        case EPDF:
            mimeType = @"application/pdf";
            userPhoto = [User getPDFPhoto];
            break;
        case ECSV:
            mimeType = @"text/csv";
            break;
        case EExcel:
            mimeType = @"application/vnd.ms-excel";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    [self sendMailPicker:picker addAttachmentUsingMimeType:mimeType];
    if (userPhoto == 1 && shouldAddZip) {
        [self sendMailAddPhotoUsingPicker:picker];
    }

    shouldAddZip = NO;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: After further testing and the use of your code, I managed to pinpoint the bug to the "send" action of the composer. As suggested by @Andrea, I monitored allocations and when presenting the mail composer, I see my memory rising up by 6.5 Mo, which is the size of the zip file. It adds up to 9.5 Mo and when I click on the send button, I start receiving 4 memory warnings and get the MFMailComposeResultFailed. So the composer caches the data without any problem but can't send it afterwards...

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the problem is related to memory, when you create NSData you create in the heap. If it is to big you'll start to receive memory warnings. One way to avoid memory could be create a memory mapped NSData or an an NSStream but I have no idea on how to integrate a NSStream in mail composer. Which is the average size of your attachment?
You can also try to profile your app with Allocations to see wich is the memory footprint of your app, maybe is already too high.

Comment: Even if is deprecated you could make a test with  +[NSData dataWithContentsOfMappedFile:], if it works change with the correct one.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't change a thing... Same failure when hitting the send button

Comment: Are you sure that on your device you have a valid email account? I mean can you send emails from it. I also found an interesting post on Apple Forums but it doesn't deal with develop https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3325644?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Yes my email account is valid and can send emails with attachments. I really think it fails because of the way the memory is handled by the mail composer...

Comment: I can't find nothing else to help you, the other thing is use an URL scheme that invokes the Mail application. By the way I really suggest you to load tha app using instruments to check the memory pressure before and during the presentation of the V.C..

Comment: I monitored allocations and when presenting the mail composer, I see my memory rising up by 6.5 Mo, which is the size of the zip file. It adds up to 9.5 Mo total and when I click on the send button, I start receiving 4 memory warnings and get the MFMailComposeResultFailed. So the composer caches the data without any problem but can't send it afterwards...

Comment: The fact is that actually I've seen 1° iPads dealing with 35Mb peak before firing memory warning. That said the "bad" memory is the dirty memory, I would try also to run allocations + VMTracker. I don't think that Apple made a class without handling attachment in the right way regarding memory issues. Maybe the problem is do related to memory pressure and it comes up in that way, but MFComposer isn't causing it, I'm telling that because if you made some reaserches on google it seems that none has a problem like that, is also true that from images app you can't send more that 5-6 images.

Comment: Even though I wasn't able to fix my issue, I have awarded you the bounty. Thanks anyway, you helped me have a clearer view on my issue. I ended up creating a fallback function to send the mail via a webserver

Answer (score 0):

like the some problems i had faced before.
1. Please check, there is internet availability using "Reachability" class file.
2. Please check your data size is within the limit.
3. Please check you configured your email id with your device. 
you can also call [yourobj cansendmail] function to check whether it can send mail or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The internet is available and my device can send mail. What is the limit for data attachment (on the device I mean) ? I know email providers limit the size, commonly to 10 Mo (like mine) but I am 'only' trying to send 7 Mo...